# Lint multiple source files and out put to corresponding txt files

Tags: makefile, lint

I'm trying to run a makefile on a directory such that it runs lint on all the cpp files in that directory and save the output in multiple files with the same names as source files. 
e.g. in other words I want to save lint out put for abc.cpp to abc.txt and def.cpp to def.txt and so on for all the unknown number of files to a sub-directory lintfiles.
some thing like the following:-

```
*lint .ALWAYS:*
   --lint-nt $(PATHS) $(OPTIONS) *.cpp > ./lintfiles/%f.txt
```

make util is not understanding Lint's `%f` option. I also tried the following but it generates no output.

```
lintfiles/%.txt: %.cpp
   -lint-nt $(PATHS) $(OPTIONS) $@ $^
```

please suggest.

Comment: `foreach` and globbing should do the trick.

Comment: In which directory is your makefile, and where do the sources lie? and are you using GNU make, or a different make? The edits of @Simon-Boudrias do not all really make sense for GNU make, especially the first makefile...

Comment: It's OPUS MAKE. The makefile is in the source directory and the out put directory "lintfiles" is also in the same dir.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pc-lint, but if the syntax is something like

```
lint-nt -o abc.lint abc.cpp
```

then this makefile should do the job:

```
SRC_DIR := src # or whatever
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
LINTS := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(SRC_DIR)/lint/%.lint, $(SRCS))

all: $(LINTS)

$(LINTS): $(SRC_DIR)/lint/%.lint : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    lint-nt $(PATHS) $(OPTIONS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Getting the following error
OPUS MAKE: makefile (line 59): No targets on dependency line. Stop.
on line $(LINTS): $(SRC_DIR)/lintfiles/%.txt : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp

Comment: Opus Make is a proprietary tool; I'm not familiar with it and I can't find a good manual for it. The makefile I gave works under GNU Make (the de facto standard).